# Removing padding and margins from Android RelativeLayout

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, formatting

[Spaces between generated layouts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddxWj.jpg)

I've tried everything, but can't figure out how to remove the spaces between each block. They're sets generated by user input, so the code is for the template

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-20dp"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    xmlns:xmls="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
```

Comment: I only see LinearLayout in the snippet. Can you share the container view code?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is, if you use recyclerview with adapter. It's a pretty good [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vyqz_-sJGFk). Obviously in the relativ layout part, you need use wrap content and match parent.